# c++ registry not getting second value

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

why is this not working? the first RegGetValue puts correct values in value variable, the second doesn't, however if I comment the first RegGetValue the second will then work and put the correct content into value2 variable. I tried closind and reopening the registry key using RegOpenKeyEx after the first RegGetValue function call but with no succes.
What I am doing wrong

```
HKEY hKey = NULL;
LSTATUS res;

res=RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "", 0, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);
if(res!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
         printf("insucces\n");
else {
    char value[255], value2[255];
    memset(value,0,255);
    memset(value2,0,255);
DWORD BufferSize = BUFFER;
RegGetValue(hKey,"\\.jpeg","",RRF_RT_ANY,NULL,(PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
strcat(value,"\\DefaultIcon");
RegGetValue(hKey,"jpegfile\\DefaultIcon","",RRF_RT_ANY,NULL,(PVOID)&value2, &BufferSize);

printf("succes %s\n",value2);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [RegGetValue manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) about your last parameter;

> pcbData [in, out, optional]
>
> A pointer to a variable that specifies
>   the size of the buffer pointed to by the pvData parameter, in bytes.
>   When the function returns, this variable contains the size of the data
>   copied to pvData.

In other words, the contents of your `BufferSize` variable is changed by the first call to be the size of the first value returned, and needs to be reset before the second call.